# Google Search Appliance newwavesearchables UDP port 2058

Tags: google-search-appliance

Anyone have any idea what services newwavesearchables rmi UDP port 2058 does?
i cant find any information on it and our GSA is creating an excessive on our firewall. I cant find any options set on the GSA web interface that would utilise this service. Is anyone able to advise if this is normal as i cant find any information about this port in the GSA documentation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of that in my 8 years of work with the GSA.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Terry, I will check out our firewall again. I just wanted to clarify i wasn't missing something, as the documentation states the same thing and that 2058 is not used.